# How to update an object value in array of objects when the keys are same

Tags: javascript, typescript, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I have an Array of objects and one object

`const filterArray = [{bestTimeToVisit: 'Before 10am'}, {bestDayToVisit: Monday}]`

This values are setting in a **reducer** and the payload will be like
`{bestTimeToVisit: 'After 10am'}`
or
`{bestDayToVisit: Tuesday}`.
So what I need is when I get a payload `{bestTimeToVisit: 'After 10am'}` and if `bestTimeToVisit` not in filterList array, then add this value to the filterList array.
And if `bestTimeToVisit` already in the array with different value, then replace the value of that object with same key

Comment: this data is a bit oddly formatted.  does each object in an array always have one key and value?

Comment: Yeah I know its oddly formatted. In javascript the objects not needs to be same in an array I think. Thats why I confused

Answer (score 0):

```
if(filterArray.hasOwnProperty("bestTimeToVisit")) {
filterArray["bestTimeToVisit"] = payload["bestTimeToVisit"];
} else {
filterArray.push({"bestTimeToVisit": payload["bestTimeToVisit"]});
}
```

Comment: filterArray is an array so it wont have any properties

Comment: Please, avoid code-only answers. Future readers will be grateful to see explained _why_ this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code.

Answer (score 0):

I convert the object array into a regular object and then back into an object array.  makes things less complicated.  I'm making the assumption each object coming back only has one key/value and that order doesnt matter.

```js
const objectArraytoObject = (arr) =>
  arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const key = [Object.keys(item)[0]];
    return { ...acc, [key]: item[key] };
  }, {});

const newValues = [{ someKey: 'something' }, { bestDayToVisit: 'Tuesday' }];

const filterArray = [
  { bestTimeToVisit: 'Before 10am' },
  { bestDayToVisit: 'Monday' },
];

const newValuesObj = objectArraytoObject(newValues);
const filterObj = objectArraytoObject(filterArray);

const combined = { ...filterObj, ...newValuesObj };
const combinedToArray = Object.keys(combined).map((key) => ({
  [key]: combined[key],
}));

console.log(combinedToArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

Need to iterate over the array and find objects that satisfy for modification or addition if none are found.

```
  function checkReduced(filterrray,valueToCheck="After 10am"){
  let isNotFound =true;
  for(let timeItem of filterrray) {
      if(timeItem.bestTimeToVisit && timeItem.bestTimeToVisit !== valueToCheck) {          
          timeItem.bestTimeToVisit=valueToCheck;
          isNotFound=false;
          break;
      }    
  }
  if(isNotFound){filterrray.push({bestTimeToVisit:valueToCheck})}  
    
}
const filterArray = [{bestDayToVisit: "Monday"}];
checkReduced(filterArray,"After 9am");//calling the function
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const updateOrAdd = (arr, newItem) => {
  // get the new item key
  const newItemKey = Object.keys(newItem)[0];
  // get the object have the same key
  const find = arr.find(item => Object.keys(item).includes(newItemKey)); 

  if(find) { // the find object is a reference type
    find[newItemKey] = newItem[newItemKey]; // update the value
  } else {
    arr.push(newItem); // push new item if there is no object have the same key 
  }

  return arr;
}

// tests
updateOrAdd([{ a: 1 }], { b: 2 }) // => [{ a: 1 }, { b: 2 }]
updateOrAdd([{ a: 1 }], { a: 2 }) // => [{ a: 2 }]
```